# How to transform block in css?

Tags: html, css

How to transform block in CSS? Pseudo-elements is need or not? I try to create block look like block on the picture below. I can't create such block as on the picture below.

**This is my code:**

```css
.transform_items {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 600px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}
.block,
.block::before{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  width: 350px;
  height: 60px;
}
.block::before {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid #52B352;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -35px;
}
.block a {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform_items">
  <div class="block"><a>Block</a></div>
</div>
```

**The expected result:**

[image]

Comment: yes it will be better to use a pseudo element if you want to keep the text straight

Comment: @Aziz Ok! I understand. But I can't create block look like block on the picture. Help me!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use SVG <sup>**(1)**</sup>, it could be like this

[**codePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/JKVdVQ?editors=1100)

```css
svg #block {
  stroke: orange;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 5
}
svg text {
  font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="274px" height="84px" viewBox="0 0 274 84">
  <polygon id="block" points="33,13 245,24 245,60 29,64 " />
  <text x="100" y="50">BLOCK</text>
</svg>
```

You can also save the svg code as a `.svg` file,*without the text element*, and use it as `background-image` for the div that contains your text

Read this to learn how to use svg in different ways: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

---

<sup>**(1)**</sup> <sub>Browser support for SVG is a little better than browser support for `transform`, [caniuse: SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)</sub>